# Karma cannot launch Chrome for Jenkins in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, ubuntu-12.04, gruntjs, karma-runner

I am trying to run karma as a grunt task on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine in Jenkins CI.  The issue I am running into is that karma will not open Chrome and gives the following error:

```
Started by GitHub push by spencerapplegate
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/rescour-roomba master/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/rescour-roomba master/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@7b41ce14
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision ee61ceea1b8728e90b01db04a1813284a524caed (origin/master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
Commencing build of Revision d3ed5ffd7c7b7a707bd9310c5bce09242e1faced (origin/master)
Checking out Revision d3ed5ffd7c7b7a707bd9310c5bce09242e1faced (origin/master)
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content
CHROME_BIN=/opt/google/chrome/

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5570746814297674358.sh
+ sudo npm install
+ sudo grunt buildProd
Loading "express.js" tasks...
[31mERROR[39m[31m>> [39mError: Cannot find module 'temp'

[4mRunning "clean:build" (clean) task[24m
Cleaning ".tmp"...[32mOK[39m
Cleaning "build/app"...[32mOK[39m
Cleaning "build/app-config"...[32mOK[39m
Cleaning "build/components"...[32mOK[39m
Cleaning "build/img"...[32mOK[39m
Cleaning "build/index.html"...[32mOK[39m
Cleaning "build/scripts"...[32mOK[39m
Cleaning "build/src"...[32mOK[39m
Cleaning "build/styles"...[32mOK[39m

[4mRunning "copy:local" (copy) task[24m
Created [36m370[39m directories, copied [36m2260[39m files

[4mRunning "compass:prod" (compass) task[24m
[31m[0m[32mdirectory[0m .tmp/styles/ 
[31m[0m[32m   create[0m .tmp/styles/main.css (1.732s)
Compilation took 1.784s

[4mRunning "template:prod" (template) task[24m

[4mRunning "clean:template" (clean) task[24m
Cleaning ".tmp/index.html.template"...[32mOK[39m

[4mRunning "karma:unit" (karma) task[24m
[36m[2013-10-07 10:07:51.709] [DEBUG] config - [39mautoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
[32mINFO [karma]: [39mKarma server started at http://localhost:8079/
[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Chrome
[31mERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start Chrome        

[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Chrome again.
[31mERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start Chrome        

[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Chrome again.
[31mERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start Chrome        

[33mWarning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.[39m

[31mAborted due to warnings.[39m
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
SSH: Current build result is [FAILURE], not going to run. 
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have set CHROME_BIN=/opt/google/chrome and it seems like it has no issue finding the executable.

Other approaches I have taken (all unsuccessful) are:
-> Create shell script to open chrome as root with flag --user-data-dir
-> Copy all chrome files to a jenkins subdirectory /home/jenkins/opt/google/chrome
-> Change ownership of all chrome files in /opt/google/chrome to jenkins

The other oddity is that when I log into the machine as the jenkins user, chrome runs the tests fine.

Please let me know if there is any more info I need to provide. Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem (including logging in as jenkins user and running successfully, including setting path for the bin), except in my case it's firefox. Did you have any success with this. If so I suggest posting the answer which I would gladly +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. After install **xvnc** plugin for Jenkins (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin), problem disappeared.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I already had it and even tried uninstall install. Although my karma run works ok, I would really prefer getting karma start to work. Are you using karma run or karma start ? Ubuntu ?

Comment: Oh. Had to tick the xvnc option in the build config. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was a misuse of karma start vs karma run. You need to have a karma server running, and use karma run in the jenkins job. See my question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124895/karma-cannot-start-firefox-with-jenkins-and-ubuntu-12-04).

**Edit**: Lehu's answer works for both start/run.