# Karma cannot start Firefox with Jenkins and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: jenkins, karma-runner

I have set up a Jenkins job that should run Firefox. Signed in to Ubuntu with the Jenkins user, I can manually launch Firefox without any problem. However, when I run the job in Jenkins, I get :

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/cbx4-ci/workspace
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:cognibox/cbx4.git
Checking out Revision c90b791227b3788c2e023fd13db74ed1664428d1 (origin/master)
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
FIREFOX_BIN=/usr/bin/firefox

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson985724635788604565.sh
+ bash -ex runkarma.sh
+ node_modules/karma/bin/karma start config/karma.conf.js --reporters junit
[32mINFO [karma]: [39mKarma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Firefox
[31mERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start Firefox

[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Firefox again.
[31mERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start Firefox

[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Firefox again.
[31mERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start Firefox
```

As you can see, I have injected the environment variable to point to Firefox.

Some useful version numbers if this can help:

Jenkins 1.546
NodeJs 0.10.24
Karma 0.10.9

Edit:

It might be good to know that I had to do an operation for the jenkins user to be able to run firefox in the first place. As my main user, I had to enable other users to launch firefox by doing `xhost +local:`. Without that, the jenkins user kept getting the following error.

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

Although this is likely a separate problem I solved, it might have incidence on the question I am asking, so I felt important to add this detail.

Comment: I dont know much about the jenkins setup with linux but i found when i can run something manually but not on Jenkins then it usually is to do with how jenkins is running on the environment and it usually lacking permissions for a particular type of connection. I would also try running the exact command on the box to see if i see anymore that what Jenkins is logging.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'running the exact command on the box' ?

Comment: The first point I would check is go to karma runtime folder (where it is run from) and then check the permissions there to execute firefox. I try to see if firefox could be started `execute` from within that folder - `commandline` (My assumption is that user who owns karma can only run firefox). And then, the karma's behavior is such that only super users can have such privileges. For me, the Jenkins permissions are a new subject altogether, though. You made it to there you are better than me in that aspect.

Comment: Unfortunately Firefox runs fine from there. Also, the command I run from jenkins I can run successfully from the command line, as user jenkins. I will update the question with additional detail I just thought of, might be useful to anyone trying to help out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. It turns out the problem originated from a misconception on how to run karma in the first place.

The Jenkins task was doing `karma start`, with autowatch set to true. Instead, I fired up karma with autowatch false in rc.local (script ran on boot) and the Jenkins task executes `karma run` instead. This solved the problem entirely.

**Edit**: Installing the [xvnc plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin), and activating it for build works for karma start and karma run.

**Edit**: The problem came back when I upgraded to 14.04. The fix was to make sure the environment variables injected in the build pointed to the X11 versions.

```
FIREFOX_BIN=/usr/bin/X11/firefox
CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/X11/google-chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind running karma with `--log-level` debug and also `--no-colors` so we can have a better idea of the reason why it fails?

I you also tried with another browser?
I often encounter issues while running a GUI tool within Jenkins.

You might want to try running your test suite with PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) just to see if a headless browser would solve the problem